# Magnolia 6 add back searchview to workbench

Tags: magnolia

does anyone know how can I add the workbench searchview back to magnolia 6?
i tried everything and I do not see any help on their website documentation.

Answer (score 2):

They are gone with Magnolia 6. Instead, there is a central mechanism to do searches across various providers @See https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/Find+Bar

If the content comes from JCR, it should be automatically enabled and if it is not coming from JCR, you can write your own so-called SearchResultSupplier.

Cheers,

Hope that helps

Comment: Hello Ducaz, thank you very much for your response, but the client allready know this and he asked me to find a way to bring it back , because in this particular task,it makes more sense to add the search there.

Comment: you can have app specific filtering added for different workbench columns. Would that suffice? or do you really need search and write custom search query?

Comment: I really need to add that searchview above the workbench similarly to the "datatable" search

Comment: but what do you want that search view to do? What's the use case for it if you will? Why does it have to be specific to the app instead of using global search functionality provided ootb by magnolia? As far as I understand the product, the local (app specific) search view was replaced with global facility which is both easier to configure and easier to develop for. So far I have not seen use case that would demand having local search bar as well. Could you help us understand the use case?

Comment: Yes, also it can filter by the app you are in. e.g. When Pages app is open, it will filter the results within the Pages app.